# Optimize RandomVariate for a $1/x^4$ distribution

Tags: random, distributions

I'm working with the following code, where I define a probability distribution proportional to $1/x^4$.

```
pdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
a^3 b^3/(b^3 - a^3)/x^4, {x, a, b}] /. {a -> 0.01, b -> 0.5};
RandomVariate[pdf, 10000]; // Timing
RandomVariate[pdf]; // Timing
```

To generate $10,000$ random variables according to this distribution or to generate 1 usually takes about the same amount of time (about 2 seconds); about half the time, $10,000$ samples is faster. I understand that there's an amazing speedup that happens because of vectorized manipulations, but this is a little ridiculous. I believe that the expensive piece here is computing the inverse CDF when I call `RandomVariate`; the actual sampling part is quite quick (hence why it doesn't care about the $10,000$ number). Is there some way to store the result of the inverse CDF computation, so I can generate appropriately sampled numbers from the same PDF quickly later on?

Comment: My apologies on the normalization - must've had a copy-paste error from when I computed it or something... Simply fixing the normalization by inserting a factor of 3 definitely speeds up the process!

Comment: Whenever you are in doubt that your PDF expression is normalized, you can do something like this: `ProbabilityDistribution[a^3 b^3/(b^3 - a^3)/x^4, {x, a, b}, Method -> "Normalize"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in Chapter 2 of our book, "Mathematical Statistics with Mathematica" (section 2.6). A free copy of the whole text (or chapter) can be downloaded from:

http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

Note that your pdf is not well-defined as it does not integrate to 1. Making that correction, your pdf has form:

[image]

Find the cdf $P(X<x)$:

[image]

where I am using the `Prob` function from the mathStatica package for *Mathematica* (or use Mathematica's `CDF` function, or just `Integrate` it yourself). Then, the inverse cdf is:

[image]

The first solution (the real one) is the one that interests us. For your case, the inverse cdf is thus:

```
blah = (a b)/(b^3 + a^3 u - b^3 u)^(1/3) /. {a -> 0.01, b -> 0.5};
```

Then, a single pseudorandom number can be generated with:

```
 blah /. u -> RandomReal[]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000035, Null}

The latter is some 200,000 times faster on my Mac than the OP's version.

Similarly, to generate  100,000 pseudorandom values:

```
 blah /. u -> RandomReal[{}, 100000]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002089, Null}

Comment: This is definitely the fastest option. As Anjan Kumar points out, after n~10, the vectorized nature of RandomVariate beats @mef's solution. Computing the appropriate root explicitly as you've done wins hands down -- I find it to be about a factor of 20 faster than RandomVariate (with the correct normalization).

Answer (score 5):

First of all your "pdf" does not integrate to one. (It integrates to 1/3.) Let's define a distribution that does integrate to one:

```
myDist[a_, b_] = ProbabilityDistribution[3 a^3 b^3/(b^3 - a^3)/x^4, {x, a, b}]
```

We can generate a random variate from this distribution:

```
RandomVariate[myDist[.01, .5]]
```

On my computer this is about 35 times faster than when using your "pdf". But that can be speeded up dramatically by computing the inverse CDF:

```
Simplify[Quantile[myDist[a, b], q], 0 < q < 1]
```

> Root[-a^3 b^3 + (b^3 + a^3 q - b^3 q) #1^3 &, 1]

We can use this to construct our own random number generator:

```
randomDraw[a_, b_] :=
  With[{q = RandomReal[]},
  Root[-a^3 b^3 + (b^3 + a^3 q - b^3 q) #1^3 &, 1]
  ]
```

Now

```
randomDraw[.01,.5]
```

produces an additional speed up of a factor of about 150. (In other words it's about 5000 times faster than using "pdf".)

Comment: Comparing the timings of  `RandomVariate[myDist[.01, .5], 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming` and `Table[randomDraw[0.01, 0.5], 10000]; // AbsoluteTiming`, `RandomVariate` is at-least 5 times faster. Looks like for a length greater than 10, `RandomVariate` is superior.  Perhaps, there is a better way to generate points without `Table` I'm not aware of.